# How to run the instance of SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server-express

How to run the SQL Server 2008 Express edition, when I go to start menu, the SQL Server 2008 R2 Configuration tools there is only one option SQL Server installation center.

When I open it there I cannot find any option how to run it, there is no option like configuration manager in configuration tools.

Did I miss something during installation, if it is so how can I get the configuration manager? :(

I have installed Visual Studio 2010, I cannot figure this thing out how to run to server, also I am new in this field Please somebody help me at this..

Answer (score 0):

You have not selected management studio while installation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're absolutely brand new, a lot of the documentation will be overwhelming, but it's too broad a question to answer here fully.  There are just too many variables - Did you get the Management Studio Express, for example?  What are you trying to do, etc?

However, there is a nice video here that may be a good starting point for you: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_3qgAxplW0